# How to prevent two events about the same thing happening

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Basically,I am a beginner in C# and I just started working on a simple platformer game following a basic Visual Studio 2015 tutorial.This is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool goleft = false;
    bool goright = false;
    bool jumping = false;

    int JumpSpeed = 10;
    int force = 8;
    int score = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            goleft = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            goright = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && !jumping)
        {
            jumping = true;
        }
    }

    private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            goleft = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            goright = false;
        }
        if (jumping)
        {
            jumping = false;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player.Top += JumpSpeed;

        if (jumping && force < 0)
        {
            jumping = false;
        }
        if (goleft)
        {
            player.Left -= 5;
        }
        if (goright)
        {
            player.Left += 5;
        }
        if (jumping)
        {
            JumpSpeed = -12;
            force -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            JumpSpeed = 12;
        }
        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {
            if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "p")
            {
                if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds) && !jumping)
                {
                    force = 8;
                    player.Top = x.Top - player.Height;
                }
            }

            if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Door.Bounds))
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("You Won!");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The gravity force and everything works great EXCEPT for one big problem with the player that I definitely can't solve without some help.

The problem is: the player is completely glitched and it keeps going up and down. I realised that this is because of two lines in `private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)`:

```
player.Top += JumpSpeed;
```

and

```
player.Top = x.Top - player.Height;
```

Both of these try to change `player.Top` and interfere with each other. The trouble is that I can't just cut one of the two without destroying the gravity force code. What I think might work is applying `player.Top += JumpSpeed;` ONLY `if(player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds) && !jumping) = false` but I don't know how to write the code this way at all (previous tries always ended up with errors).

Thanks in advance for any help and please forgive any grammar errors that I made because I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: Visualizing question is better than explaining with words. Even I got your question and tried to work with your code. I really can't know what the player is? Please share a code that we can use directly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how your Form looks like, but with what you provided I would change the code like that:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool goleft = false;
    bool goright = false;

    int JumpSpeed = 0; //current vertical speed
    int force = 8; //initial jump speed
    int score = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            goleft = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            goright = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && JumpSpeed==0) //JumpSpeed==0 to prevent "double jump"
        {
            JumpSpeed = force; //start jumping with full power
        }
    }

    private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            goleft = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            goright = false;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (goleft)
        {
            player.Left -= 5;
        }
        if (goright)
        {
            player.Left += 5;
        }

        JumpSpeed -= 1; //decrement the vertical speed = gravity -> choose higher value to bring him back on the ground quicker
        player.Top -= JumpSpeed;


        if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Door.Bounds))
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("You Won!");
            this.Close();
        }


        foreach (PictureBox x in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
        {
            if (x.Tag == "p")
            {
                if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds)) //if the player should be able to jump/walk on something the code is
                {
                    player.Top = x.Top - player.Height;
                    JumpSpeed = 0; //the player stops falling
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make sure to player does not fall out of the window place PictureBoxes with tag == p on the floor!

**PS:**

Feel free to leave a comment!